# How to check a string not containing number in the middle using RegEx?

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays of strings.

1. valid strings
2. invalid strings

I want any string containing a number in the middle to be invalid. How can I check these types of strings using RegEx in JavaScript?
In the code below the valid array work perfectly but in the invalid array the string (Badus3rnam3) passes Validation.

```
    const validArr = ['Jo', 'Ocians11', 'RegexGuru', 'JACK', 'Z97', 'AB1'];
    const invalidArr = ['BadUs3rnam3','J', '007', '9', 'A1',  'c57bT3', 'J%4'];

    validArr.forEach(element => {
        const myReg = /(^[a-zA-Z]+\d*$){3,}|^[a-zA-Z]+\d\d+$|^[a-zA-Z]{2,}/;

        if (myReg.test(element)) {
            console.log(`OK Valid string: ${element}`);
        }
        else {
            console.log(`Invalid string: ${element}`);
        }
    });
```

Comment: It looks like you have much more complex validation than just "doesn't contain number", unless you typed random symbols in your regex. I'd suggest a better description of the problem.

Comment: ^ otherwise something like `^(\D.*\D|\D)$` would work

Comment: My advise would be to split logic. You don't need 1 massive regex to check for validity. Separate the logic, use 1 regex for each check instead of cramping them all into 1.

Comment: A simple `\d\D` would match a number that is not at the end of the string (invalid scenario). `const hasNonEndNumber = !!string.match(/\d\D/)`

Comment: Thank you all. Your comments helped me to modify me RegEx and finally this one helped me:  { /^[a-zA-Z]+(\d){2,}$|^[a-zA-Z]{2,}\d*$/  }

Comment: I don't understand why `AB1` is valid but `A1` is invalid.

Answer (score -1):

After five hours trying finally this RegEx worked for me to validate username with bellow conditions:

1. Usernames can only use alpha-numeric characters.
2. The only numbers in the username have to be at the end. There can be zero or more of them at the end.
3. Username cannot start with the number.
4. Username letters can be lowercase and uppercase.
5. Usernames have to be at least two characters long.
6. A two-character username can only use alphabet letters as characters.

   /^[a-zA-Z]+(\d){2,}$|^[a-zA-Z]{2,}\d*$/

Comment: These conditions should have been in your original question.

Comment: Exactly, I am new to Stack Overflow. I was thinking the invalid array I have defined was sufficient to understand. Thanks for your comment I learned how to ask the next Question.